# How to send a sorted result from my MongoDB database by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code where i send my collection to index.ejs

```js
router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    FILM
        .find().limit(6)
        .then(films => res.render('index.ejs', {films}))
})
```

In `index.ejs` I want to sort my collection by rating from button.
What way can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in `index.ejs` an anchor tag that would send a request to `/` with a url param, something like this for example:

```
<a href="/?sort=1">Sort</a>
```

You change you request handler, so that when there is a query parameter, it send a sorted list, otherwise send a normal one.

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const sort = req.query.sort;
  if (sort) {
    FILM.find()
      .sort({ rating: 1 })
      .limit(6)
      .then((films) => res.render("index.ejs", { films }));
  } else {
    FILM.find()
      .limit(6)
      .then((films) => res.render("index.ejs", { films }));
  }
});
```

Comment: how can i do the same without reloading the page?

Comment: It's more tricker. You should send a non sorted data as you did before, make it available inside a `script`, execute JavaScript code in the browser to sort that array, and then render the html there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    var sortFilter = { rating : 1 };
    FILM.find().sort(sortFilter).limit(6)
        .then(films => res.render('index.ejs', {films}))
})
```

Please [refer docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/sort) for more information